# JSON - make subchild as a condition for IF Statement

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON from an API with this content:

```
"items":[
     {
      id: *id here*,
      variant: {
             variant_name: *name here*,
             variant_id: *id here*,
             stores: {
                   0: 
                      store_id: *STOREID1*,
                      available_for_sale: true
                   1: 
                      store_id: *STOREID2*,
                      available_for_sale: true
     }
   }
}]
```

I want to select the items with the same store ID and Available for sale status. I have tried this but this isn't working:

```
if(items.variant.stores.store_id === "STOREID1" && items.variant.stores.available_for_sale === 'true'){
```

But it says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store_id' of undefined
```

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
 if(items.variants.stores.store_id["******"] && items.variants.stores.available_for_sale['true']){
```

But it still gives the same error.

EDIT 2:

Edited the Question for more clarification.

Comment: Do you mean items with a specific store_id and status? or just grouping in general? Please clarify the question

Comment: Sorry, im talking about specific store IDs and statuses

Comment: You have to iterate over the array in items and filter them out based on the ones you want.  It's not enough to just check one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file is malformed.  I've tried to fix it to be valid. Next time take the object you get in the console.log, and instead use `JSON.stringify(jsobject)` for valid JSON output instead of trying to copy paste it verbatim.

It's not entirely clear if you want the whole object, or just the stores values.  But I've implemented both.

I've used `Object.values`, because your notation looks like objects (which would make it invalid JSON), but if they are really arrays, you shouldn't need `Object.values`.

```js
data = {
  "items": [{
    id: "*id here*",
    variant: {
      variant_name: "*name here*",
      variant_id: "*id here*",
      stores: {
        0: {
          store_id: "*STOREID1*",
          available_for_sale: true
        },
        1: {
          store_id: "*STOREID2*",
          available_for_sale: true
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}

// filter for and return whole object for any that have the stores in question
// use some to to search for at least one match of store values
console.log(
  data.items.filter(item => Object.values(item.variant.stores).some(({
    store_id,
    available_for_sale
  }) => store_id === '*STOREID1*' && available_for_sale))
)

// get stores values
// Using flatMap to combine all the arrays returned from each stores object.
console.log(
  data.items.flatMap(item => Object.values(item.variant.stores).filter(({
    store_id,
    available_for_sale
  }) => store_id === '*STOREID1*' && available_for_sale))
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry if the JSON was malformed, it was too long and i don't want to post it because it might look messy.

Answer (score 1):

`items` is an array, you need to iterate over it and filter the items you want

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    variant: {
      variant_name: '*name here*',
      variant_id: 111,
      stores: { store_id: 1111, available_for_sale: true }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    variant: {
      variant_name: 'name here',
      variant_id: 222,
      stores: { store_id: 2222, available_for_sale: true }
    }
  }
];

const result = items.filter(({variant: v}) => (
    v.stores.store_id === 2222 && v.stores.available_for_sale
));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```